# BAD_DATA error when calling any contract function on ethers

Tags: ethers.js, foundry

Im getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method": "symbol", "signature": "symbol()" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.11.1)
```

This is the function causing the error:

```js
  async function getSymbol() {
    signer = await provider.getSigner();

    ShareContract = new ethers.Contract(
      "0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512",
      abi,
      signer,
    );

    let call = await ShareContract.symbol(); // this line fails
  }
```

I deploy the contract with
`forge script DeployShare --rpc-url http://127.0.0.1:8545 --private-key 0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80 --broadcast`

And I get a successful deployment:

[image: successful deploy]

I have made sure the address I input is the correct one as shown on the image.